# Move snackbar above the bottom nav bar jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-snackbar, android-bottomnav

I am creating custom `Snackbar` using Jetpack Compose. But I have also implemented `BottomNavBar` using `Scaffold`. Everything works fine but only one problem is snackbar goes under the `BottomNavBar`. So how to move above to the `snackbar` over `BottomNavBar`?

Snackbar code:

```
@Composable
fun DefaultSnackbar(
    snackbarHostState: SnackbarHostState,
    onDismiss: () -> Unit?,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    SnackbarHost(
        hostState = snackbarHostState,
        modifier = modifier,
        snackbar = {data ->
            Snackbar(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                content = {
                    Text(
                        text = data.message,
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
                        color = White
                        )
                },
                action = {
                    data.actionLabel?.let { actionLabel ->
                        TextButton(
                            onClick = {
                                onDismiss()
                            }
                        ) {
                            Text(
                                text = actionLabel,
                                style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2,
                                color = White
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    )
}
```

Bottom Navigation Code :-

```
@Composable
fun BottomNav()
{
    BottomNavigation(
        elevation = 15.dp,
        modifier = Modifier.zIndex(5f)
    ) {
        BottomNavigationItem(
            icon = {Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Search, contentDescription = "search icon", tint = Color.White)},
            selected = false,
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ }
        )
        BottomNavigationItem(
            icon = {Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Home, contentDescription = "search icon", tint = Color.White)},
            selected = true,
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ }
        )
        BottomNavigationItem(
            icon = {Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.MoreVert, contentDescription = "search icon", tint = Color.White)},
            selected = false,
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ }
        )
    }
}
```

Calling snackbar :

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
@AndroidEntryPoint
class RecipeListFragment : Fragment() {

    private val viewModel: RecipeListViewModel by viewModels()

    private val snackbarController = SnackbarController(lifecycleScope)

    @ExperimentalComposeUiApi
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            setContent {

                AppTheme(darkTheme = viewModel.isDarkTheme.value) {

                    val recipes = viewModel.recipes.value
                    val query = viewModel.query.value
                    val selectedCategory = viewModel.selectedCategory.value
                    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()

                    Scaffold(
                        topBar = {
                            SearchBar(
                                query = query,
                                onQueryChange = viewModel::onQueryChange,
                                selectedCategory = selectedCategory,
                                onSelectedCategoryChanged = viewModel::onSelectedCategoryChanged,
                                onToggleTheme = viewModel::onToggleTheme,
                                searchRecipe = {
                                    if (viewModel.selectedCategory.value?.value == "Milk") {
                                        snackbarController.getScope().launch {
                                            snackbarController.showSnackbar(
                                                scaffoldSate= scaffoldState,
                                                message = "Milk is in Snack",
                                                actionLabel = "Hide",
                                            )
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        viewModel.searchRecipe()
                                    }
                                }
                            )
                        },
                        bottomBar = { BottomNav() },
                        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
                        snackbarHost = {scaffoldState.snackbarHostState},
                    ) {

                        Box(modifier = Modifier
                            .background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)
                            .fillMaxSize())
                        {
                           ...
                           others items 
                           ...

                            CircularIndeterminateProgressBar(display = viewModel.isLoading.value)

                            DefaultSnackbar(
                                snackbarHostState = scaffoldState.snackbarHostState,
                                onDismiss = { scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.currentSnackbarData?.dismiss()},
                                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the scaffold code that is being used to display your bottom navigation and snackbar. Include the code that displays your snackbar.

Comment: As Johann already said, it'll be much easier for us to reproduce, if you share a complete example that we can just copy and paste, that is represting your issue.